# How do I summarize the total number of radio button selection values (Letters, and not numbers)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radiobuttonlist

I would like to be able to have my form selection choices (radio buttons) added up at the end of a questionnaire in a HTML form, to give me a summary of all the answers with a total number displayed per choice. In other words, there are 10 questions, each with a possible answer of A, B, C or D. At the end of the form, I would like the user to be able to see how many A's they answered, how many B's etc.

Here is what I've been able to put together so far...

```
<input name="Q1" type="radio" value="A" />A.
<input name="Q1" type="radio" value="B" />B. 
<input name="Q1" type="radio" value="C" />C. 
<input name="Q1" type="radio" value="D" />D.

<input name="Q2" type="radio" value="A" />A.
<input name="Q2" type="radio" value="B" />B. 
<input name="Q2" type="radio" value="C" />C. 
<input name="Q2" type="radio" value="D" />D.
```

My Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#radio_submit").click(function (e) {
var checked_Q1_radio = $('input:radio[name=Q1]:checked').val();
var checked_Q2_radio = $('input:radio[name=Q2]:checked').val();

if(checked_Q1_radio===undefined || checked_Q2_radio===undefined)
    {
        alert('Please answer all the questions');
    }else{
        alert('Question 1. - "' +checked_Q1_radio + '"'+'Question 2. - "'   
    +checked_Q2_radio + '"');
    }
   });
});
```

This gives me an alert window, and shows a summary of my answers, which is ok.

But I still can't figure out how to display the total of the different choices as I described above - because the research I've done has only lead me to examples where number values are added up, which won't work in my case. Am I looking at the problem from the wrong angle?

If it's not possible, how could I then:

1. Separate (line break) the 2 results in my alert message?
   What will work instead of the '+'? I have tried '\n' and '%n' but
   obviously my formatting is incorrect. What would work instead?
2. It takes much longer now to load the page, is there a reason for
   that?

Thanks for the assistance- I really hope to be up to speed with all of this coding soon enough then I won't have to ask silly questions :-)

And I hope that I haven't overstepped any boundaries that will upset any of the forum members. Again, I am very grateful for any assistance #learningfromthebest

Comment: What do you mean by "added up"?  What result do you want when (say) the "A" is selected in the first question and "C" in the second? What do you want to do with that result?

Comment: OH sorry I just re-read your first paragraph. I see.

Comment: @Pointy I would like to have a summary to show the user how many A answers they gave, how many B answers they gave etc (There are 10 questions in total), which will allow them to see what product they need - Mostly A answers, then you need product X, Mostly B answers, then you will need product Y. I hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a string of all the selected values like this:

```
var values = $('input:radio:checked').map(function(radio) { return this.value; })
    .get()
    .join("");
```

Then you can count the "A", "B", "C", and "D" values like this:

```
var counts = { A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0 };
values.replace(/[ABCD]/g, function(letter) {
    counts[letter]++;
});
alert("A's: " + counts.A + " B's: " + counts.B + " C's: " + counts.C + " D's: " + counts.D);
```

*edit* here's a slightly less icky and more functional way to do it:

```
var counts = $('input:radio:checked').map(function(radio) { return this.value; })
    .get()
    .reduce(function(c, letter) {
        c[letter]++;
        return c;
    }, { A: 0, B: 0, C: 0, D: 0 });
```

Comment: Requires a modern JavaScript environment for `.reduce()`, but that's getting to be less and less of a problem.

Comment: Thanks soooo much, it works! Yay!! Is there a way to display each answer on its own line?

Comment: You can put `"\n"` between the counts, but honestly `alert()` is going to be pretty limited in terms of pretty output :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#radio_submit").on("click", function () {
    var msg = "A: " + Count("A") + "\n"
            + "B: " + Count("B") + "\n"
            + "C: " + Count("C") + "\n"
            + "D: " + Count("D");

    alert(msg);
});

function Count(type) {
    return $("input[type=radio][value='" + type + "']:checked").length;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wv0nkyr4/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert('Number of checked A answers: ' + $('input:radio[value="A"]:checked').length.toString())
```

Explanation of the selector:
With `input:radio[value="A"]` you are telling jQuery to search for all the `input` elements of type `radio` which has the value "A". Then, with `:checked` you are telling to get only those elements which are checked.

Finally, with the property `lenght` you are getting the quantity of elements that jQuery has found and has added to the jQuery object.